# Function Value Retrieval: how to access the value of a variable outside a function. and how use that value in another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

**I've written a code to print the IP address corresponding to the mac address given. the thing is the IP is inside the retrieve_input function. how can i get the IP value outside the retrieve_input function?
Here is my code.**

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome..")
a = str(subprocess.getoutput(["arp", "-a"]))
print(a)
text=a
def retrieve_input():                   #retrive input and fetches the IP
    inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    ext = inputValue
    if (inputValue in a and inputValue != ''):
        nameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
        ip = nameOnly.split()[-2]
        print(ip)

window.geometry('900x700')
lbl1=Label(window, text="MAC ADDRESS",width=15,height=2,font=2)
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt=Text(window, width=25,height=1)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="CONVERT",fg="black",bg="light 
grey",width=15,font=4,height=2,command=lambda:(retrieve_input())
btn.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Uh use `globals` ?

Comment: globals won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def retrieve_input():                   #retrive input and fetches the IP
    inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    ext = inputValue
    if (inputValue in a and inputValue != ''):
        nameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
        ip = nameOnly.split()[-2]
        return ip
    else:
        return False

ip_value = retrieve_input()
```

You can use return IP if you don't want to use global variables, with that function can return IP adres that you would like to use.

However there is another approach if you you know Python Classes and attributes.

```
class IpValues:

    def __init__ (self):
        # Initialize and use it as constructor
        self.ip = None
        pass

    def retrieve_input(self):                   
        # retrive input and fetches the IP
        inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        ext = inputValue
        if (inputValue in a and inputValue != ''):
            nameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
            self.ip = nameOnly.split()[-2]


ip_values_object = IpValues()
ip_values_object.retrieve_input()
print(ip_values_object.ip)
```

Comment: in the first case, can i get the value of ip outside the retrieve_input function?

Comment: suppose if i've one more function, can i use the same ip value?

Comment: ok, I will modify my answer how you can do that, with return function you can get the variable outside of the function, However other answer would be better for you.

Comment: I added a line at the end of my first code, as you can see you can Return a value from a function store it on "ip_value" and you can use it outside the function.

Comment: i'm getting error as NameError: name 'txt' is not defined as i tried to print ip_value. any thing wrong with inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")??????

Comment: put print (ip) inside of your code if it works my print(ip_value) would also work, I dont know what else you wanted to with your func. my friend

Comment: @krishna could you please select an answer if  the code was helpful for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ip` a global variable like this:

```
def retrieve_input():
  global ip #declare ip as a global variable                   
  ip = "0.0.0.0" #assign a value to ip

retrieve_input()
print(ip) #access the value of ip outside the function
```

In your code, it would look like this:

```
def retrieve_input():
    global ip #declare ip as a global variable
    inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    ext = inputValue
    if (inputValue in a and inputValue != ''):
        nameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
        ip = nameOnly.split()[-2] #assign a value to ip
        print(ip)
```

Comment: but the value of ip is inside the if loop right? can i access it directly outside the if loop?

Comment: You can access `ip` from anywhere in the code as long as you declare it as a global variable. See my edit.

Comment: i tried it. but i'm getting error as    print(ip)
NameError: name 'ip' is not defined

Comment: def retrieve_input():
    global ip                  
    inputValue=txt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    ext = inputValue
    if (inputValue in a and inputValue != ''):
        canvas.config(background="green")
        nameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
        ip = nameOnly.split()[-2]
        print(ip)
print(" ************************************** ")
retrieve_input()
print(ip)

Comment: here i'm getting error as NameError: name 'txt' is not defined